# Iteration error writing file to excel with python

Tags: excel, python-2.7

```
import string
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\T\file.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
book = open_workbook(r'C:\T\test.xls','r')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
     print sheet.cell(row_index,0).value
     x = sheet.cell(row_index,0).value
     worksheet.write_string(row_index,col_index,x)
workbook.close()
```

I'm a skiddy to python. Here i'm trying to read the xls file with **xlrd** for data and copy it to another xlsx file through **xlsxwriter** module. but the data won't get pasted in the created *xlsx* sheet. Please guide me through this. *Above* is my exact code. Please correct me if any wrong.

*A volley of Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example program almost works. Mainly it needs the `open_workbook()` method to be prefixed with a class and it is better to use XlsxWriter `write()` instead of `write_string()` unless you are sure that all the data you are reading is of a string type. Also, the program was only reading values from column 0.

Here is the same example with those changes in place. I've also renamed the variables `in_`  and `out_` to make it clearer which module is calling which method:

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

out_workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
out_worksheet = out_workbook.add_worksheet()

in_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r'test.xls', 'r')
in_worksheet = in_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_index in range(in_worksheet.nrows):
    for col_index in range(in_worksheet.ncols):
        cell_value = in_worksheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value
        out_worksheet.write(row_index, col_index, cell_value)
        print cell_value

out_workbook.close()
```